# Find the binary of a file uploaded using ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I am creating a website where the user can upload a document as PDF.
It is my understanding that a file, once uploaded, it is saved as a binary file in the database.

I want to find how this document is saved (in binary) by ActiveStorage. Basically, I need to retrieve in my controller the 0s and 1s of that specific file.

I want to know how I can retrieve this binary file (as a string).

I need the binary because I want to hash it in order to compare the hash of a PDF with a hash of another PDF and say if they are identical.

In addition: if a user upload the **same** PDF file two times. Is the binary in ActiveRecords the same?

Comment: Where do you save your files? On database or on file system?

Comment: Now I am using Postgres (not sure if it is what you asked, sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that, Active Storage computes a Base64-encoded MD5 digest of your file, available via `checksum` method.

[ActiveStorage::Blob#checksum](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L234)

Comment: Thanks. So how can I find a unique identifier for the content of that specific PDF? It is not clear to me what the `checksum` method gives me back or how I can use it.

Comment: The checksum is an unique identifier, it is a hash digest, (example: 27848dbbd8800a97720d7b5a77092b17) If you save the same file twice the cheksum will be the same.

Comment: Thanks, but where do I get it from? Should be something like `@document.checksum` in my controller?

Comment: model_instance.attachment_assoc_name.checksum, https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html